# How can i find page is resumed?

Tags: windows-phone-7, lifecycle

Am using pages in my application and let me explain simply for your understanding.

I have pages `A,B` and `C`. 
From page `A -> page B`,
page `A -> page C` are possible.

I need to do a action only when the page A is resumed from page B and not from page C.

How can i make it possible, can i be able to send some flag data back to page A from page B's `OnBackPressed`. And if so where can i listen to get that flag data in page A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). When navigating from `B` to `A`, add your QueryString to the URL:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PageA.xaml?PreviousPage=b", UriKind.Relative));
```

Then, in `A's` `OnNavigatedTo`method, you can check what the value of the `PreviousPage` QueryString and react accordingly if its value is `b`.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)  
{
     base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

     string prevPage="";

     NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("PreviousPage", out prevPage);

     if(prevPage == "b")
     {
         //code to call if A is resuming from B
     }    
}
```

**Update based on comment (will leave the code above for others)**

There are a couple of options regarding the `BackKey`. Firstly, you can use the code above and then delete that particular page from the history. You can do this by using the [RemoveBackEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) method within the code above:

```
if(NavigationService.CanGoBack)
   NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

You can see more about the [Back Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394012%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) here.

Alternatively, you could keep track of a global variable, in `App.xaml.cs` for example, that is updated whenever a user leaves a page. Then, in `A`, you can check that variable and see what the previous page was (and reset the variable if need be so that it's not read again accidentally).

Comment: NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PageA.xaml?PreviousPage=b", UriKind.Relative)); --> This will add a new page and there will be two Page A in stack right? I need to destroy the page B and go back to page A.

Comment: @arnp Ah yes, sorry I forgot you wanted it via the back key. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

In your `App.xaml.cs` create `public static PhoneApplicationPage PrevAppPage;`

Initialize it in `Page b` and `Page C` constructors and on Page A in the `onNavigatedTo` event check its value. And do respective work.

or you can create `enums` and initialize them in the page constructors and check the value in the `page A's onNavigatedTo` event.

Either method should work